# Java log4J with multiple file, and need to remove instance name from logfile

Tags: java, log4j

I am creating multiple log file in my java project, and that code is working perfectly. My code is giving below:

```
    # Root logger option
log=../logs
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.logger.normalFile=DEBUG, fileAppender
log4j.logger.reportFile=DEBUG, reportAppender

log4j.additivity.normalFile=false
log4j.additivity.reportFile=false

log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=${log}/normalLOG.log
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

log4j.appender.reportAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.reportAppender.File=${log}/reportLOG.log
log4j.appender.reportAppender.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.reportAppender.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.reportAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.reportAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
```

when i checked my log file , i got output something given below:

```
2016-07-30 12:17:44 INFO  normalFile- Reading from C:\
```

2016-07-30 12:17:44 INFO  normalFile- Processing file 
2016-07-30 12:17:48 INFO  normalFile- New Record added

Instead of log instance (**normalFile**) name , i need to put my working class name in log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation, you can change the line where the conversion pattern is to this one

log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1} - %m%n

So, changing the %c to %C you get the what you are looking for. Anyway you can read the docs for more information.[log docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%C` instead of `%c`.

From [Docu](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html):

> C -    Used to output the fully qualified class name of the caller issuing the logging request.

But mind that this will have a **huge impact on performance**.

Another (and probably better) possibility would be to alter the config so you get Loggers with the according class names:

```
Logger myLogger = LogManager.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
```

But then you'd have to change your config to add the appender either directly to the root logger or some logger based on your application's package.

Example assuming your application uses the package "my.application":

```
log4j.logger.my.application=DEBUG, fileAppender
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you pass to [`LogManager.getLogger(String )`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/LogManager.html#getLogger(java.lang.String)) method. Whatever you pass there will appear in the log as the name of the logger.

If you want to have your class there, simply pass the class name or directly the class itself:

```
Logger myLogger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
// or better
Logger myLogger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

Also note that the `1` in `%c{1}` causes to output just the last part of the class name (i.e. without the package). Use just `%c` to output fully qualified class name.

Comment: If i pass my class name in getLogger method, how can it will identified my log file name. For example i have to right debug log in normalfile.log and error log in report.log.

Comment: @Andy Read log4j manual to understand how that works. Log4j will traverse a tree to find a logger that matches the logger name. So a logger (in java code) created with class my.app.className will be matched to a logger defined in config by the name of "my.app". If there is no such logger it will fall through to rootLogger. If you want to filter different LogLevels to different files, you need to use Filters.

Comment: @Andy If I remember correctly, [Filters](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/LevelMatchFilter.html) need to be configured through xml configuration. They are not available in properties config.

Comment: @Andy : Generally the code shouldn't be aware where the logging goes and should only identify itself with the class name. Then it's matter of configuration which class goes to which file. Anyway, `%c` gets the information from this name. There is other way - `%C` which uses stack trace to determine the caller but first it's terribly slow, secondly it's unreliable when you pass the message through another call for example.